# Hive Case Resulting Duplicate Row

Tags: sql, database, hive, hql

I have a table containing contact numbers and another reference table containing a "length" variable and a number column. 
What I need is to find the prefix name where the prefix of the number matches the one in the reference table, but it should be the one that goes with the longest prefix matching. (omg I hope that make sense)

What I've tried so far:

```
select a.record_type,a.number,b.prefix,b.prefix_name 
from first_table a , second_table b 
where  a.transaction_date=20180924 and case  
    when b.length=1 then substr(a.number,1,1)=b.prefix  
    when b.length=2 then substr(a.number,1,2)=b.prefix  
    when b.length=3 then substr(a.number,1,3)=b.prefix  
    when b.length=4 then substr(a.number,1,4)=b.prefix  
    when b.length=5 then substr(a.number,1,5)=b.prefix  
    when b.length=6 then substr(a.number,1,6)=b.prefix  
    when b.length=7 then substr(a.number,1,7)=b.prefix  
    when b.length=8 then substr(a.number,1,8)=b.prefix 
    when b.length=9 then substr(a.number,1,9)=b.prefix 
    when b.length=10 then substr(a.number,1,10)=b.prefix 
    when b.length=11 then substr(a.number,1,11)=b.prefix 
    when b.length=12 then substr(a.number,1,12)=b.prefix 
    when b.length=13 then substr(a.number,1,13)=b.prefix 
    when b.length=14 then substr(a.number,1,14)=b.prefix 
end
```

However it still returns duplicate result, i.e: if the number is 12345, it matches the reference with prefix 1234 and 123, while I actually just want the 1234 one.

Is there any way to like prioritize the case? Thanks

An example of the data in the two tables:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntj91.png)

My current result and the desired result: [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqVfR.png)

Comment: You probably need to have your conditions in a join statement. Please provide some sample date from the two tables and it is easier to help you..

Comment: @W_O_L_F added the sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I reworked it, try this:

```
    WITH FIRST_TABLE (RECORD_TYPE,NUM,TRANSACTION_DATE)AS (
    SELECT 'a',12345, DATE '2018-09-24' FROM DUAL
    ),
    SECOND_TABLE (PREFIX,PREFIX_NAME,LENGTH) AS(
    SELECT 12,'Type A', 2 FROM DUAL union all
    SELECT 1234,'Type B', 4 FROM DUAL 
    )
    select * from (
    SELECT A.RECORD_TYPE,A.NUM,B.PREFIX,B.PREFIX_NAME, MAX(B.PREFIX) OVER (PARTITION BY A.RECORD_TYPE,A.NUM) maxPrefix
    FROM FIRST_TABLE A ,SECOND_TABLE B
    WHERE  A.TRANSACTION_DATE=DATE '2018-09-24' 
    AND A.NUM LIKE (B.PREFIX||'%')
    )
    where PREFIX=maxPrefix;
```

Comment: I've tried this but it still gives me similar result to the one I did. So i.e. the number 12345 still matches with 123 and 1234. Btw do you mind to explain the first part of your answer (WITH FIRST TABLE ......................) ?

Comment: The WITH statement (in this case) is a way to create a table in memory without me having to actually create one in the database. It is also a nice way to show some sample data.  You can skip the first 7 rows... Did you run the whole query or just the last part when you got your latest result? If you still have a problem please add similar With statements to your query. It is a neat way to show some sample data.

Comment: I ran the last part starting from SELECT A.RECORD_TYPE, however I still got multiple result

Comment: Then please add some more sample data.

Comment: in my case the number 6285893484300  matches with prefix 628589348 and 6285893

Comment: I tried the new one but it says: 
FAILED: ParseException line 5:40 cannot recognize input near '|' ''%'' ')' in expression specification

Comment: I am using oracle database. the || means concatinate. You need to use your database's convention. What db are you using?

Comment: according to: https://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/string-functions-in-hive.html it looks like you can use .... LIKE (CONCAT(B.PREFIX,'%'))...... But then again I never used Hive.

Comment: that works fine! Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it

Comment: no worries, happy to help. It was an interesting problem-

Comment: @Gin . . . This is essentially the second solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select ap.*
from (select a.record_type, a.number, p.prefix, p.prefix_name,
             row_number() over (partition by  a.record_type, a.number order by p.length desc) as seqnum
      from first_table a join
           second_table p
           on (p.length = 1 and substr(a.number, 1, 1) = p.prefix) and
              (p.length = 2 and substr(a.number, 1, 2) = p.prefix) and
              . . . 
              (p.length = 14 and substr(a.number, 1, 14) = p.prefix)    
      where a.transaction_date = 20180924 
     ) ap
where seqnum = 1;
```

This can be phrased more succinctly as:

```
select ap.*
from (select a.record_type, a.number, p.prefix, p.prefix_name,
             row_number() over (partition by  a.record_type, a.number order by p.length desc) as seqnum
      from first_table a join
           second_table p
           on substr(a.number, 1, p.length) = p.prefix    
      where a.transaction_date = 20180924 
     ) ap
where seqnum = 1;
```

Another method does the comparisons using individual `join`s and stops at the first match:

```
select a.record_type, a.number,
       coalesce(p14.prefix, p13.prefix, . . . , p1.prefix) as prefix,
       coalesce(p14.prefix_name, p13.prefix_name, . . . , p1.prefix_name) as prefix_name
from first_table a left join
     second_table p14
     on p14.length = 14 and substr(a.number, 1, 14) = p14.prefix left join
     second_table p13
     on p13.length = 13 and substr(a.number, 1, 13) = p13.prefix and p14.prefix is null left join
     second_table p12
     on p12.length = 12 and substr(a.number, 1, 12) = p12.prefix and p13.prefix is null left join
     . . .
     second_table p1
     on p1.length = 1 and substr(a.number, 1, 1) = p1.prefix and p2.prefix is null
```

Comment: I tried your approach (the rephrased one) but it says "Line 6:14 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'prefix'
Can you please explain how does the query suppose to work? @Gordon Linoff